# Scheme if expression returns '#<void>' if the body contains an expression

Tags: scheme, sicp

So I am currently reading SICP and I am stuck at exercise 1.22, since I do not understand why my program isn't working the way I intend it to work. Here is the Code

```
#lang sicp
; the given function to time the search for a prime
(define (timed-prime-test n)
    (newline)
    (display n)
    (start-prime-test n (runtime)))
(define (start-prime-test n start-time)
    (if (prime? n)
        (report-prime (- (runtime) start-time))))
(define (report-prime elapsed-time)
    (display " *** ")
    (display elapsed-time))

; finds the smallest natural number that can divide n without any remainder
(define (smallest-divisor n)
    (define (square x)
        (* x x))
    (define (divides? a b)
        (= (remainder a b) 0))
    (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
        (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
              ((divides? n test-divisor) test-divisor)
              (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
    (find-divisor n 2))

; returns true if the given number n is prime
(define (prime? n)
    (= n (smallest-divisor n)))

; start searching at start and found keeps track of the amount of
; primes found, if it equals 3 return found
(define (search-for-primes start found)
    (if (= found 3)
        found   ; after finding 3 primes above start return
        ((timed-prime-test start)    ; if not continue search with start + 1
         (search-for-primes (+ start 1) (if (not (prime? start))
                                            found
                                            (+ found 1))))))

(search-for-primes 1000 0)
```

The problem is that when I run this program it works fine until it finds a prime number. The interpreter that I use is racket and the program terminates with:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments...:
   3
1019 *** 0
```

If I understand the interpreter correctly than it should evaluate this expression according to the applicative-order evaluation principle right? So why is it passing the `if` expression as a procedure to my `search-for-primes` procedure? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `search-for-primes`, if you have more than one expression in one of the legs of an `if`, then you need to put them inside a `begin` block - surrounding it with `()` won't work. This should fix the problem:

```
(define (search-for-primes start found)
  (if (= found 3)
      found
      (begin ; add this!
        (timed-prime-test start)
        (search-for-primes (+ start 1) (if (not (prime? start))
                                           found
                                           (+ found 1))))))
```

Comment: I am not sure if the author intends one to use `begin` to solve the problem, but besides that: this fixes the issue I had! thanks

Comment: @emn What I think is that the author intended for you to measure the time differently, not right in the middle of the function. You should measure it outside, in the calling point, in that way you won't need to use `begin`.